# C# mongo driver ignores connection timeout?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm connecting to mongodb instance and it all works fine :

```
async void Main()
{
    string connection = "mongodb://....:27017/authdb?connectTimeoutMS=3000&socketTimeoutMS=3000";
    MongoClient client = new MongoClient(connection);
    Console.WriteLine(client.Settings.ConnectTimeout );
     
   try
    {           
         client.ListDatabaseNames(); //dummy operation
         Console.WriteLine("done");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }

}
```

output:

```
00:00:03
done
```

This means that the query string value is inserted to the `client.Settings.ConnectTimeout` property.

But now I want to see if the timeouts I've declared in the query string are working. So I'm going to change to a wrong IP address.

When I change to a wrong IP , I get the following exception after 30 seconds :

> ```
> A timeout occurred after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors =
> ```
>
> MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector,
> LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000
> } }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", Type :
> "Unknown", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId
> : 1, EndPoint : "....:27017" }", EndPoint:
> "10.153.14.188:27017", ReasonChanged: "Heartbeat", State:
> "Disconnected", ServerVersion: , TopologyVersion: , Type: "Unknown",
> HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An
> exception occurred while opening a connection to the server. --->
> System.TimeoutException: **Timed out connecting to .....:27017.
> Timeout was 00:00:03.**
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.TcpStreamFactory.d__7.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.TcpStreamFactory.d__4.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.d__51.MoveNext()
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.d__51.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.d__32.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.d__34.MoveNext()",
> LastHeartbeatTimestamp: "2021-07-12T13:39:27.6777575Z",
> LastUpdateTimestamp: "2021-07-12T13:39:27.6777575Z" }] }.

This happens after 30 seconds and not after 3 seconds as I declared in the query string.

**Question**

How can I make `MongoClient` trying to connect and exit after 3 seconds, as declared in the query string ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can I make MongoClient trying to connect and exit after 3 seconds, as declared in the query string ?

You can add the `serverSelectionTimeoutMS` in the connection string to handle this. Per the documentation:

> serverSelectionTimeoutMS - Specifies how long (in milliseconds) to block for server selection before throwing an exception. Default: 30,000 milliseconds.

Update your connection string per below:

```
 string connection = "mongodb://....:27017/authdb?serverSelectionTimeoutMS=3000&connectTimeoutMS=3000&socketTimeoutMS=3000";
```

For more information about these connection options, please [see](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/) the documents.